# Retagging time-complexity

Tags: discussion, tags

[time-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-complexity) is a confusing mess. Its current excerpt reads:

> for challenges requiring the answers to be in a certain time complexity, or having a winning criterion about the time complexity.

which are two very different properties for a question to have, one of which duplicates [fastest-algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-algorithm). However, it only has 9 questions, so it shouldn't be too hard to retag. What's the best way to retag?

Comment: [Related](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1889/194)

Comment: For some reason I keep reading the title as "Ragtime Complexity"

Comment: @AlexA. I read it as "Ragtag time-complexity."

Answer (score 16):

Those which are [fastest-algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-algorithm) should obviously be retagged with that. For those which require answers to be in a certain time complexity, I propose creating [restricted-time-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-time-complexity) by analogy with [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source). Then [time-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-complexity) can be left for the cleanup script to delete.

Comment: It turns out that `restricted-time-complexity` is too long to be a tag. I've made it `restricted-complexity`; for space complexity, `restricted-memory` should be acceptable.