# We're getting a new moderator: Cast your votes!

Tags: discussion, moderators

[As announced last week](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5688/8478) PPCG is getting another moderator. You've had one week to nominate others or yourself, and now it's time for the actual election. The candidates are:

- [Beta Decay](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5692/8478) (vote [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5745/26997))
- [ProgramFOX](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5706/8478) (vote [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5746/26997))
- [Alex A.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5691/8478) (vote [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5747/26997))
- [PhiNotPi](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5695/8478) (vote [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5748/26997))
- [Dennis](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5693/8478) (vote [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5749/26997))

I will add one (community wiki) answer for each one of them. You may vote on as many of them as you want, and the candidates are welcome to vote as freely as anyone else (including for themselves). Voting will close after 7 days.

Best of luck to the candidates!

Answer (score 46):

## [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis)

[image: profile for Dennis at Programming Puzzles & Code Golf Stack Exchange, Q&A for programming puzzle enthusiasts and code golfers]
 
[image: profile for Dennis at Programming Puzzles & Code Golf Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A for programming puzzle enthusiasts and code golfers]

[**Nomination Post**](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5693/8478)

## Stats

[**Main**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012?tab=topactivity)

- member since December 19, 2013
- 15 questions
- 421 answers
- 43 posts edited
- 12 helpful flags
- 1531 votes cast

[**Meta**](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/12012?tab=topactivity)

- 5 questions
- 9 answers
- 1 post edited
- 0 helpful flags
- 113 votes cast
- currently 15th overall in [participation](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=participation)

[**Chat**](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/37160)

- user since April 20, 2012
- 31 all time rooms
- 2176 all time messages
- ~179 messages per week recently

Answer (score 30):

## [Alex A.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20469/alex-a)

[image: profile for Alex A. at Programming Puzzles & Code Golf Stack Exchange, Q&A for programming puzzle enthusiasts and code golfers]
 
[image: profile for Alex A. at Programming Puzzles & Code Golf Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A for programming puzzle enthusiasts and code golfers]

[**Nomination Post**](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5691/8478)

## Stats

[**Main**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20469?tab=topactivity)

- member since April 16, 2014
- 1 question
- 151 answers
- 136 posts edited
- 8 helpful flags
- 1921 votes cast

[**Meta**](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/20469?tab=topactivity)

- 3 questions
- 15 answers
- 5 posts edited
- 1 helpful flag
- 303 votes cast
- currently 2nd overall in [participation](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=participation)

[**Chat**](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/141888)

- user since March 4, 2015
- 13 all time rooms
- 7470 all time messages
- ~740 messages per week recently

Comment: I have no clue why Alex's main flair is missing the profile picture.

Comment: Is it? It's showing up fine for me.

Comment: @ProgramFOX That's even weirder. :D

Answer (score 22):

## [ProgramFOX](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9275/programfox)

[image: profile for ProgramFOX at Programming Puzzles & Code Golf Stack Exchange, Q&A for programming puzzle enthusiasts and code golfers]
 
[image: profile for ProgramFOX at Programming Puzzles & Code Golf Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A for programming puzzle enthusiasts and code golfers]

[**Nomination Post**](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5706/8478)

## Stats

[**Main**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9275?tab=topactivity)

- member since October 5, 2013
- 11 questions
- 56 answers
- 294 posts edited
- 406 helpful flags
- 2046 votes cast

[**Meta**](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/9275?tab=topactivity)

- 11 questions
- 37 answers
- 20 posts edited
- 26 helpful flags
- 769 votes cast
- currently 16th overall in [participation](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=participation)

[**Chat**](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/88521)

- user since August 19, 2013
- 51 all time rooms
- 11915 all time messages
- ~165 messages per week recently

Comment: I voted you up because you overwhelmingly have the most edits and helpful flags.

Comment: ProgramFOX has been *exceedingly* helpful on community projects like [Charcoal](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq), which owns SmokeDetector, among other things. He knows the SE model. I can vouch for him.

Answer (score 17):

## [PhiNotPi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/2867/phinotpi)

[image: profile for PhiNotPi at Programming Puzzles & Code Golf Stack Exchange, Q&A for programming puzzle enthusiasts and code golfers]
 
[image: profile for PhiNotPi at Programming Puzzles & Code Golf Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A for programming puzzle enthusiasts and code golfers]

[**Nomination Post**](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5695/8478)

## Stats

[**Main**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/2867?tab=topactivity)

- member since October 2, 2011
- 50 questions
- 75 answers
- 7 posts edited
- 1 helpful flag
- 379 votes cast

[**Meta**](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2867?tab=topactivity)

- 6 questions
- 53 answers
- 8 posts edited
- 0 helpful flags
- 73 votes cast
- currently 64th overall in [participation](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=participation)

[**Chat**](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/24697)

- user since October 6, 2011
- 28 all time rooms
- 10759 all time messages
- ~54 messages per week recently

Answer (score 2):

## [Beta Decay](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/30525/beta-decay)

[image: profile for Beta Decay at Programming Puzzles & Code Golf Stack Exchange, Q&A for programming puzzle enthusiasts and code golfers]
 
[image: profile for Beta Decay at Programming Puzzles & Code Golf Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A for programming puzzle enthusiasts and code golfers]

[**Nomination Post**](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5692/8478)

## Stats

[**Main**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/30525?tab=topactivity)

- member since August 11, 2014
- 35 questions
- 80 answers
- 31 posts edited
- 4 helpful flags
- 793 votes cast

[**Meta**](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/30525?tab=topactivity)

- 9 questions
- 26 answers
- 3 posts edited
- 0 helpful flags
- 118 votes cast
- currently 5th overall in [participation](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=participation)

[**Chat**](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/124789)

- user since August 14, 2014
- 12 all time rooms
- 2420 all time messages
- ~340 messages per week recently

Comment: Your avatar gives and impression that your reputation is -15. :)

Comment: @Zerotoinfinity Haha blame Optimizer ;)

Comment: This is not what I asked you to do :|

Comment: @Optimizer Oh yeah, you wanted it to look like 0/-15 on the one box...