# A heartfelt welcome to our new moderator...s!

Tags: discussion, moderators

We've got some big news today! What is *with* the "s" in the title? I'm very happy to announce that the community team has appointed *two* new moderators pro tempore. [You've cast your votes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5744/8478), so let me welcome both **Dennis** and **Alex A.** to the mod team!

[image: profile for Dennis at Programming Puzzles & Code Golf Stack Exchange, Q&A for programming puzzle enthusiasts and code golfers]
 
[image: profile for Dennis at Programming Puzzles & Code Golf Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A for programming puzzle enthusiasts and code golfers]


[image: profile for Alex A. at Programming Puzzles & Code Golf Stack Exchange, Q&A for programming puzzle enthusiasts and code golfers]
 
[image: profile for Alex A. at Programming Puzzles & Code Golf Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A for programming puzzle enthusiasts and code golfers]

They've both been exceptional users and exceptionally friendly and I'm sure they'll both make great moderators. Welcome Dennis and Alex!

Please also join me in well-wishing [dmckee](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78/dmckee), who is stepping down after 4.5 years of service to this community. He has done some great work for this site, including [naming our beloved Nineteenth Byte](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte).

Comment: At first I thought it was a moderator whose username was "s"!

Answer (score 49):

I just want to take a moment to say

## THANK YOU!

Yes you! Thank *you* specifically. If you're reading this, I thank you.

I'm absolutely honored to be a moderator for this wonderful, quirky community and I'll do everything I can to serve it. PPCG is a very special place. Thank you all so much for your kindness and support, it means more to me than you can imagine.

As an aside, in case you're feeling duped, like information had been withheld from you, I didn't know about this until last Friday. Stack Exchange contacted me and asked if I'd like to be a mod for PPCG, which thoroughly confused me given that Dennis won our informal election by popular vote, but here we are on Monday and Dennis and I both have diamonds. A special thank you to the Stack Exchange team.

## <3